# vips: unknown action "dzsave"

Tags: windows, vips, libvips

Ok, I am feeling rather stupid right now...

I have installed vips on my windows computer from

https://github.com/libvips/build-win64-mxe/releases/download/v8.14.2/vips-dev-w64-all-8.14.2.zip

Extracted it and typed `vips dzsave` from with in the bin directory.

I did this on my personal laptop (windows 10) and also on a Windows server 2019.

I am getting the following error: `vips: unknown action "dzsave"`

[image]

I installed it on my windows 10 VM and it worked.

I don't see a mention of prereqs as I am downloading the build version.

Thoughts?

Gina

Answer (score 1):

They pulled the functionality out 8.14.2 because of licensing issues.

https://github.com/kleisauke/net-vips/issues/203

Comment: Though only from the precompiled windows binaries. It's still in 8.14.2 on all other platforms.

Comment: There's a PR https://github.com/libvips/libvips/pull/3476 to put it back, it'll return in 8.14.3, or perhaps 8.15.